# How to remove Notes on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, uninstall, notes

I've been trying to find a way on how to remove notes on Kubuntu, unfortunately I couldn't.
When I right-click on the icon there's no option to remove the note.

Comment: it looks like you have two running notes application in there, isn't it? Have a look into the `ps aux` for the application and try to kill one of them.

Comment: No, for a note there is an icon, if I wrote 4 notes then I'll have  4 icons, I don't think it has anything to do with that.

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the answer to this.  Click and hold on the body of the note, and a little vertical bar will appear to the right of the note.  The bar has a red x at the bottom.  Release your mouse, click the x, and good riddance to a really really really annoying app.

Comment: This is correct, here's a screenshot that illustrates the solution: https://imgur.com/a/jUks3Sp

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about the same notes as I have on Ubuntu (Simple notebook for GNOME 3.14.2), there is menu button in the top right corner, where you can find option "Move to trash".

Comment: Nope, it's like a note that appears as an icon in the navigation bar.

Comment: so at least write what you see if you can't make print screen.

Comment: Well I just deleted my navigation bar and created a new one with same settings as before and I didn't had any notes on it, but I'll try  to capture aswell so you can see  how it looks like.

Comment: I edited the post with a link to my screencap !

Answer (score -1):

If you right-click on your bar, then click on Options and then on Parameters, you'll see another larger bar appear with options to modify the bar. Don't do anything. Just run your mouse over the application you want to close and you'll see a window with a red x in it. Click this and it will close the app.